# Is It Possible To Choose IOS Wide Angle Camera In React Native Expo App?

Tags: react-native, expo, qr-code, expo-camera, react-native-vision-camera

I am new to react-native ecosystem. I was recently building a simple qr code scanner with expo react native using expo camera.

What I found out was that there is no option to manually select wide angle camera in expo camera, It just selects the default camera. I tried expo-barcode-scanner as well but it also doesn't have this option. I found out that react-native-vision-camera has this option but it is not supported in expo (You could do the expo prebuild but it will require either macos or an apple developer account to test on iphone and I am on linux so this is not feasible).
Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.